# Python Pandas: Create new column out of other columns where value is not null

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame like this

```
----------------
RecID| A  |B
----------------
1    |NaN | x 
2    |y   | NaN 
3    |z   | NaN
4    |NaN | a 
5    |NaN | b
```

And I want to create a new column, C, from A and B such that if A is null then fill with B and if B is null then fill with A:

```
----------------------
RecID|A   |B    |C 
----------------------
1    |NaN | x   |x
2    |y   | NaN |y 
3    |z   | NaN |z
4    |NaN | a   |a
5    |NaN | b   |b
```

Lastly, is there an efficient way to do this if I have more than two columns, e.g. I have columns A-Z and want create a new column A1 out of columns A-Z similar to above?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the general solution you were looking for.  You now have over 15 reputation.  Feel free to up vote any answers you find useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of multiple columns, you can use forward fill. This example assumes that you want to build a combination of all columns 'A' through 'Z':

```
df['AZ'] = df.loc[:,'A':'Z'].fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)['Z']
```

This method works for two columns, too:

```
df['C'] = df.loc[:,'A':'B'].fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)['B']
#0    x
#1    y
#2    z
#3    a
#4    b
```

Comment: How will this work if the columns I want to pull values from into the new column are not in order?

Answer (score 13):

***`pandas`***
*`lookup`*
This is the generalizable solution OP was looking for and will work across an arbitrary number of columns.

```
lookup = df.loc[:, 'A':'B'].notnull().idxmax(1)
df.assign(A1=df.lookup(lookup.index, lookup.values))

   RecID    A    B A1
0      1  NaN    x  x
1      2    y  NaN  y
2      3    z  NaN  z
3      4  NaN    a  a
4      5  NaN    b  b
```

*`fillna`*

```
df.assign(C=df.A.fillna(df.B))

   RecID    A    B  C
0      1  NaN    x  x
1      2    y  NaN  y
2      3    z  NaN  z
3      4  NaN    a  a
4      5  NaN    b  b
```

*`mask`*

```
df.assign(C=df.A.mask(df.A.isnull(), df.B))

   RecID    A    B  C
0      1  NaN    x  x
1      2    y  NaN  y
2      3    z  NaN  z
3      4  NaN    a  a
4      5  NaN    b  b
```

*`combine_first`*

```
df.assign(C=df.A.combine_first(df.B))

   RecID    A    B  C
0      1  NaN    x  x
1      2    y  NaN  y
2      3    z  NaN  z
3      4  NaN    a  a
4      5  NaN    b  b
```

***`numpy`***
*`np.where`*

```
df.assign(C=np.where(df.A.notnull(), df.A, df.B))

   RecID    A    B  C
0      1  NaN    x  x
1      2    y  NaN  y
2      3    z  NaN  z
3      4  NaN    a  a
4      5  NaN    b  b
```

Comment: Are these all doing _exactly_ the same thing? I'm trying to follow up and they all look like they would behave in the same way (outside of this specific example)?

Comment: @roganjosh Almost the same thing.  `fillna` assumes you already have nulls to be filled.  `mask` is making nulls and filling them in the same method call.  `combine_first` will also include new indices from the passed argument.  It so happens that it is another column from the same dataframe and therefore the same index.

Comment: Appreciated. Combined with your comment, this is an excellent resource for me :)